# What's the meaning of elements in this sentence?

Tags: word-meaning, sentence-meaning

> “I appreciate your having battled the elements to come here and tell us so.”

What's the meaning of elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When used in this way 'the elements' usually refers to bad weather, e.g. strong winds, heavy rain or heavy snow. It is possibly a call back to the traditional 'four elements' of earth, wind, water and fire that ancient philosphers believed were the constituents of the world.